# What is the appropriate Data URI to use for 0-byte content?

Tags: specifications, null, uri

I have a method that generates a data URI from a byte array. In the event the input byte array is empty, what is the appropriate thing for the method to do? Here are the options I see:

1. return `data:,`
2. return an empty String
3. throw an Exception

By my read, [RFC 2397](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397) doesn't explicitly address the notion of empty data.

Comment: Options #2 and #3 aren't URIs, and exceptions should only be used for exceptional circumstances or errors. I believe the question therefore answers itself.

Comment: @amon, you're assuming a valid data URI can exist when there is no data. I'm not convinced of that. On what grounds do you make that assumption?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RFC 2397 explicitly allows empty data. Let's look at the relevant parts of the grammar:

```
dataurl    := "data:" [ mediatype ] [ ";base64" ] "," data
...
data       := *urlchar
```

The `*` quantifier means zero or more repetitions, the square brackets contain optional parts. Therefore the shortest data-URL is indeed `data:,`. In your context, you'll probably use `data:text/plain;base64,` or something like that instead.